# How to formally define eigenvalue of a matrix in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm struggling at how does one define matrix eigenvalue. In my textbook, we defined eigenvalue of linear transformations and everything was fine until I reached a corollary which states
"Every real (field is $\mathbb{R}$) symmetric matrix has eigenvalue". So I thought I skipped the part where it defines or at least explains what would be the eigenvalue of a matrix. However, that part doesn't exist.

After searching online, only definition I could find was something involving $Av = \lambda v$, where $A$ is quadratic matrix, $\lambda$ is a scalar and $v$ is a vector. We didn't formally define matrix-vector multiplication since vectors are just elements of a vector space, so I can't accept that as a definition. My guess would be that we should either use matrix representation of a vector either define it using characteristic polynomial. Thoughts ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: matrix-vector ..what? You multiply two matrices or a scalar with a matrix.

Comment: @AlvinL exactly.

Comment: You've already pinpointed what you're missing: "We didn't formally define matrix-vector multiplication"... so, define it, as done in the answer of @StinkingBishop for example.

Comment: An Eigenvalue is a solution in $\lambda$ of $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}v_j=\lambda v_i$ where $a_{ij}$ are the elements of the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ (and the $v_i$ are other unknowns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb F$ be a field (e.g. $\mathbb R$).

Every matrix $A\in M_{mn}(\mathbb F)$ gives rise to a linear map $L_A:M_{n1}(\mathbb F)\to M_{m1}(\mathbb F)$ (i.e. it maps column-matrices of size $n$ to column-matrices of size $m$) by plain matrix multiplication: $L_A(x)=A\cdot x$. People often call those column-matrices "column-vectors", by the way.

On the other hand, of course, column-matrices for a fixed size make up a vector space over $\mathbb F$, and if you have *any* linear map $L:M_{n1}(\mathbb F)\to M_{m1}(\mathbb F)$, you can prove that there is a matrix $A:M_{mn}(\mathbb F)$ such that $L=L_A$. In fact, this matrix $A$ is actually the *matrix of $L$ in the suitably chosen pair of bases in $M_{n1}(\mathbb F)$, $M_{m1}(\mathbb F)$*: take the most natural bases you can:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix},\ldots,\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\\vdots\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

and *these* are the bases in which $L$ has the matrix $A$ such that $L=L_A$.

You can now go even further and prove that the map $A\to L_A$ is the *isomorphism* of the vector spaces $M_{mn}(\mathbb F)$ ($m\times n$ matrices) and $L(M_{n1}(\mathbb F), M_{m1}(\mathbb F))$ (linear maps between column-matrices of size $n$ and column-matrices of size $m$).

Thus, it makes sense to *identify* any $m\times n$ matrix with a linear map of column-matrices (of size $n$) to column-matrices (of size $m$). In this particular case, the eigenvalues of a square *matrix* $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ are just the eigenvalues of the corresponding *linear operator* $L_A\in L(M_{n1}(\mathbb R))$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ over a field $K$. We say $\lambda\in K$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if there exists a non-zero $v\in K^n$ such that $Av=\lambda v$.

$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $\det (A-\lambda E) = 0$. In other words, the system $Av = \lambda v$ has a non-zero solution.